# How can I view this webpage

Tags: safari, web-browser, websites, content-blocker, macos

I have disabled all ad blockers for [this page](https://www.howtogeek.com/722948/how-to-search-open-tabs-in-safari-on-mac/#:%7E:text=(Alternately%2C%20you%20can%20select%20View,in%20the%20top%2Dright%20corner.)) (to my knowledge!) as one can see in the settings window on top right, and yet I cannot see it:

[image]

I am using Safari 13 on a 2013 iMac.

Comment: Have you tried a deeper page like https://www.howtogeek.com/contact/ or https://www.howtogeek.com/page/terms-of-use/ ?

Comment: Can you view it in a new Private Window? ⇧⌘N

Comment: It works fine on my Safari. Enable the content blocker

Comment: @bmike these work fine ‍♂️

Comment: @IconDaemon No :(

Comment: @Ruskes it made zero difference :(

Comment: Safari 14, Mojave - *with* ad blocker (AdGuard). No issue.

Comment: I am still unable to see the page since I posted the question